# tomcat basic authentification

Tags: java, apache, security, tomcat

i want to secure a personel tomcat in following way.

Basically everyone (every ip) should be able to access the webapps of this tomcat.

But some of the ip should able to access the tomcat without authentification (most of them) and some (e.g. 10.0.0.*) should only be able to access this tomcat via an authentification.

I've read much about how to solve this problem. The Tomcat Remote Access Filter and Remote Host Name isn't working in my case, cause i don't want to deny/allow the webapp for some IP Adresses.

I've tried to add these lines to context.xml with expectation, that i (localhost) can access the tomcat without authentification, but the authentification was still required:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" invalidAuthenticationWhenDeny="true" allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator" />
```

So im at the end of my knowlegde (maybe i dont have much :D).

Can someone give me an example or a solution to my issue? Maybe i have to edit more than this file? Or did i missinterpreted something?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell you should secure web applications on Tomcat, not the server itself: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using authentication in tomcat.
1. if you want that each web app is not access by every user you can implement "Realm Configuration" . with this configuration , every time when user access the deployed web app in tomcat ,

it will ask user name and password.
for more details please refer below link:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

2. Another scenario is if you want that specific ip user able to access tomcat the via Remote filter you can achieve this.
   for more details Refer below link:
   https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Host_Filter

As you told "The Tomcat Remote Access Filter and Remote Host Name isn't working in my case, cause i don't want to deny/allow the webapp for some IP Adresses."

In that case you can implement "Realm configuration" if you don't want to bind the web app for IPs. That's why you can try to use realm configuration with user name and password.

If you still want to use remote filter then share your procedure which you are following for understanding where you are getting failed.

Comment: Hi, what i want to achieve is, that every ip needs to authentificate with user + password but e.g. my local ip (or localhost 127.0.0.1) does not have to authentificate itself. So i want to configure some ips, which do not have to authentificate. This should be "the way to go" for the whole tomcat.

Comment: Realm Configuration is useful in the case when you want to access web application for specific user with specified role with that user. Using this feature, we can mention the user with password in web application's configuration file with role and can bind users list with that role. After this , only authenticated user is allowed to access web application. To allow only some ip to access web application, then follow the remote filter with deny and allow section. As per your requirement you need to implement both realm configuration and remote filter

Comment: Ex: If you have 4 ips and you want to provide authenticated access for two ips then implement realm configuration for two ips i.e mention user name and password with role for those two Ips. JDBCRealm will work only for those ips and other two IPs can be configured with remote filter(allow or deny as per the requirement).